# Need to Improve Performance of SQL Query using Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, aggregate-functions

I have a particular SQL query that seems to suffer from a mysterious performance issue. Here is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(LengthOfTime) AS TotalTime, 
       SUM(LengthOfTime) AS TotalLength, 
       SUM(LengthOfTime) / COUNT(LengthOfTime) AS AverageTime, 
       SUM(Pops) / COUNT(LengthOfTime) AS AveragePop 
  FROM ((SELECT * 
           FROM (SELECT *, ID & YearRec AS ID2 
                   FROM MyFirstTable 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT *, ID & YearRec AS ID2 
                   FROM Table2011) AS TEMP 
          WHERE STARTTIME >= '8/1/2011 00:00:00' 
            AND StartTime <= '8/5/2011 23:59:59' ) AS TEMP2 
  JOIN AppleTable ON TEMP2.Reason = AppleTable.Skills ) 
  JOIN PeopleTable ON TEMP2.Operator = PeopleTable.Operators 
 WHERE AppleTable.[ON] = 1 
   AND PeopleTable.[ON] = 1 
   AND Rec_Type = 'SECRET AGENT'
```

The issue here is that this query runs very quickly (0:00 to 0:02) when run for a 5 day span, but very slowly (1:20 to 1:45) for a 6 day span.

There are approximately 105,000 records per day in the Tables (MyFirstTable and Table2011).

***My question***: Is there an upper limit to the number of rows you can pass an aggregate function before you see a serious performance issue in SQL Server? (currently using 2008 R2)

Comment: are your statistics up to date, have you rebuilt indexes recently?

Comment: Sounds like you may be overflowing from an in-memory operation to one requiring disk.  I'm not familiar with MySQL tuning details, but if there is a memory allocation parameter for temporary workspace, you could try increasing that.

Comment: pls add table references to the aggregate functions so we know what tables the columns come from

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - I just built the indexes before testing this query out. I'm not sure what you mean by statistics

Comment: @OMG Ponies - The tables have the exact same columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no pre-defined upper limit for aggregate functions.

The skew in performance is likely affected by one or multiple of the following:

- Old and/or unsuitable index structure
- Cached execution plan
- Cached data
- data size not being uniform (the first five days are 10 rows while the sixth is 100 B rows)

You can run the query in SSMS and view the actual execution plan. This will tell you the places where the cost of running the query is the highest, and that will help you determine the best course of action.

**Edit based on comments:**

If there isn't an index on `Table2011` that contains `[STARTTIME]`, then create one. If there is an index, but it is getting ignored, then you have to figure out why. If the is fragmented, then rebuilding the index will definitely help. Here is how to rebuild

`ALTER INDEX [YourIndexName] ON [dbo].[Table2011] REBUILD WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON);`

Alternately you can do this in SSMS - browse to the specific index in the object browser, right click and rebuild.

Comment: I looked at the actual execution plan. 97% of the Cost is coming from the "Table Scan" on Table2011. This is after I predicated the StartTime before the UNION

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using the Actual Execution Plan to create a new index 
`USE [DatabaseName]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [QueryIndex1]
ON [dbo].[Table2011] ([Rec_Type],[StartTime])
INCLUDE ([Operator],[LengthOfTime],[Pop],[Reason])
GO`

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No, there's not some magic number of records that will cause MSSQL to start performing poorly.

Now, it's possible queries won't scale well and, as a result, the larger the dataset the [exponentially] worse it performs.

A large problem you're going to have is that you're predicating the StartTime *after* the UNIONED statements. Instead, try predicating on that in both of your selects prior to the UNION. That should make a huge difference, especially if you index both tables on StartTime (generating index seeks on those tables).

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, ID & YearRec AS ID2 FROM MyFirstTable 
   WHERE STARTTIME >= '8/1/2011 00:00:00' 
   AND STARTTIME <= '8/5/2011 23:59:59'
UNION ALL SELECT *, ID & YearRec AS ID2 
FROM Table2011
   WHERE STARTTIME >= '8/1/2011 00:00:00' 
   AND STARTTIME <= '8/5/2011 23:59:59'
) AS TEMP
```

You may be able to do some additional refactoring of your code as well.

Comment: I'll give +1 for spotting the location of the `UNION`. If it can be moved further out (having the 2 tables separately joined to the others and grouped and then use the aggregates), it may increase perfomance further. You may not even need UNION in the end, only using `countFromSubquery1 + countFromSubquery2 AS TotalTime`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but the query optimizer should handle this - and the query plan should show whether this condition is applied inside sub parts ir outside the union. Should make ZERO difference in performance.

Comment: @Derek Kromm - This seems to drastically help for 5 day or less span, but I'm still running into problems with the 6 days or more span.